# What is the difference between user-level threads and kernel-level threads?

Tags: operating-systems, terminology, concurrency, os-kernel

After reading several sources I'm still confused about user- and kernel-level threads.

In particular:

> Threads can exist at both the user level and the kernel level

What is the difference between the user level and kernel level?

Comment: Is this really Comp Sci (theory) or just programming?

Comment: @Mehrdad, Operating Systems is a part of computer science.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One of the roles of a multitasking operating system kernel is [scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29): determining which thread of execution to execute when. So such a kernel has some notion of [thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29) or [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). A thread is a sequential piece of code that is executing, and has its own [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) and sometimes other data. In an operating system context, people usually use *process* to mean a thread that has its own memory space, and *thread* to mean a thread that shares its memory space with other threads. A process can have one or more threads.

Some operating systems, for example older unix systems, only provide processes: every thread that the kernel manages has its own memory space. Other operating systems, for example most modern unix systems, allow processes to contain multiple threads of execution: they provide a kernel-level notion of threads.

It's also possible for a process to manage its own threading. In [cooperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking#Cooperative_multitasking.2Ftime-sharing) multithreading, the code of each thread contains instructions to switch to another thread. In [preemptive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) multithreading, the process requests periodic [asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous) notifications from the kernel, and reacts to these notifications by switching to a different thread. This way, multithreading is implemented with no kernel cooperation, at the user level, in a library.

A system can offer both kernel-level and user-level threads; this is known as [hybrid threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29#M%3aN_.28Hybrid_threading.29).

User- and kernel-level threads each have their benefits and downsides. Switching between user-level threads is often faster, because it doesn't require resetting memory protections to switch to the in-kernel scheduler and again to switch back to the process. This mostly matters for massively concurrent systems that use a large number of very short-lived threads, such as some high-level languages ([Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29#Concurrency_and_distribution_orientation) in particular) and their [green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads). User-level threads require less kernel support, which can make the kernel simpler. Kernel-level threads allow a thread to run while another thread in the same process is blocked in a [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call); processes with user-level threads must take care not to make blocking system calls, as these block all the threads of the process. Kernel-level threads can run simultaneously on multiprocessor machines, which purely user-level threads cannot achieve.

Comment: Your last line says "Kernel-level threads can run simultaneously on multiprocessor machines, which purely user-level threads cannot achieve". But, the given link says, ULT can run simultaneusly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791801/how-do-user-level-threads-ults-and-kernel-level-threads-klts-differ-with-reg. Am I getting anything wrong ?

Comment: Can you please check my above comment ?

Comment: @Garrick Multiple user-level threads can run on different cores at the same time, provided that they're running inside different kernel-level threads. If you only have ULT as a tool, you're limited to a single processor. If KLT are available, you can spread the kernel threads over multiple processors and dispatch your ULT among the available kernel threads.

Answer (score 5):

Think of kernel level threads as "*virtual processors*" and user level threads as simply *threads* (Let's call them as such for now). Now, for a thread to be executed, it has get assigned on to a processor right? So, each thread gets assigned to a virtual processor so that it can be executed.

Here are facts

- Creating a new virtual processor is a bit costly. (The kernel has to create an entry in [Thread Control Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_control_block), assign stack etc.)
- Creating a thread is pretty simple compared to creating a new virtual processor. An application developer can create threads using Thread Libraries provided by the programming languages and are managed in *User Space*. And [different languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Programming_language_support) implement *multithreading* in different ways.

### Models

- If threads are mapped onto a single virtual processor, then one must be careful not to make a blocking system call in any of the threads, because other threads can no more run concurrently.
- This limitation can be overcome if a few more virtual processors can be created. Now, threads can run concurrently (in parallel if multiple real processors are present). A thread will not effect other threads which are mapped on other virtual processors.
- In the latter model, either one or many threads can be mapped onto a virtual processors.
- The above models are named Many to One, One to One and Many to Many respectively.

<sub>Referenes: Operating system concepts by Galvin et al. Topic: Threads -> Multithreading Models</sub>